# Prove the function is strictly increasing on $(0,1]$ for any positive integer $a$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the function $${1\over x^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^a{{a\choose i}ix^i\over (-1)^i}$$is strictly increasing on $(0,1]$ for any positive integer $a$.

The first derivative is$${1\over x^3}\sum\limits_{i=1}^a{{a\choose i}i(i-2)x^i\over (-1)^i}$$

Comment: Try checking the value of the first derivative.

Comment: @Qwerty I've tried that but I couldn't prove that its first derivative is positive on (0,1] either.

Comment: Edit the question and state what is the first derivative you found

Comment: I think You can write it as $\frac{(1+ix)^a}{x^2(-1)^i}$

Comment: @AakashKumar $i$ is a variable not the imaginary unit

Comment: @AakashKumar I don't think that is equal.

Comment: $\sum_{r = 0}^n{ ^nC_r{a^{n-r}}b^r}=(a+b)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}k kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}k kx^{k-1}=x\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}(x-1)^n=nx(x-1)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out.